# What free video editing software is capable of moving/rotating a sprite atop video?

Tags: video-editor, editing, software

Can anyone please advise: I'm looking for a recommendation on free video editing software that can:

1. Overlay a sprite (static image with transparency, e.g. .gif) atop a video,
2. Move and rotate the overlaid sprite over some specifiable portion of the video,
3. Mask the sprite, (i.e. create a movable/changeable shape that covers the sprite but is invisible in the video).

Sorry if my terminology is primitive - it's been years since I last dabbled with video editing software; I'm not sure how terminology has evolved since then.

---

I'd be grateful if the recommended software also had a tutorial -- either built-in or easily findable online -- on how to do the above.

Answer (score 4):

A great tool for this is Davinci Resolve: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve. It is very capable, has an excellent free version and can easily accomplish the desired tasks.

A quick intro to Animating a Spite/Image over Video is shown here:

-- *Davinci Resolve - How to Move Images (Animate Movement)*

A quick intro to Masking can be seen here:

-- *Masks in DaVinci Resolve 16*